# How to express current date and time as UTC in dayjs / moment?

Tags: timezone, momentjs, dayjs

I need to get current date and time in UTC regardless of current timezone. So if my current local time is 12:00 and I'm in UTC+1:00, I want to get 12:00 UTC.

How can I achieve this easily in moment.js or day.js?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a library for this.

```
new Date()                // gets a Date object representing "now"  (internally in UTC)

new Date().toISOString()  // returns "now", in UTC, formatted as an ISO 8601 string
```

If you really want to use Moment:

```
moment.utc()              // gets a Moment object representing "now", set to UTC mode

moment.utc().format()     // returns "now", in UTC, with the default ISO 8601 format

moment.utc().toISOString() // does the same thing
moment().toISOString()     // does the same thing
```

Day.js requires the [UTC plugin](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/blob/dev/docs/en/Plugin.md#utc), but then works similar to Moment.